# Pesquisa TMemo Delphi

Tags: delphi

Boa tarde a todos!
Estou fazendo pesquisa por nome completo em um TMemo com Delphi, quando o nome inteiro encontra-se na mesma linha funciona bacana, porém se parte do nome está numa linha e a outra parte na linha seguinte, a pesquisa não encontra. Alguma ideia pra solucionar isso?

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn4Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  acha:string; 
begin 
  if (Memo1.GetTextLen > 0) then 
  begin 
    zPessoa.First; 

    if not zPessoa.Eof then 
      repeat acha:=zPessoanome.Value; 

    if pos(acha, AnsiUpperCase(memo1.Lines.text))>0 then begin
```

Comment: Como está seu código, no momento?

Answer (score 1):

Deve-se utilizar o `Memo.Lines.Text` para tal:

```
  if Pos('Nome', Memo1.Lines.Text) > 0 then
    ShowMessage('Achou')
  else
    ShowMessage('Não achou');
```

Se precisar saber o número da linha:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Pos('Nome', Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then
      ShowMessage('Texto encontrado na ' +IntToStr(i+1) +'ª linha');
  end;
end;
```

No seu código, o problema é que `acha` também precisa ser UpperCase, senão ele sempre vai comparar, por exemplo, **João Silva** com **JOÃO SILVA**, o que sempre vai dar diferença.

```
if not zPessoa.Eof then    
   repeat acha := AnsiUpperCase(zPessoanome.Value);
```

Após o assunto ser melhor explicado, o seu problema pode ser resolvido substituindo a quebra de linha por espaço, utilizando Replace (StrUtils):

```
if Pos('Nome', Memo1.Lines.Text.Replace(sLineBreak, ' ')) > 0 then
  ShowMessage('Achou')
```

Comment: O código tá funcionando muito bem, o problema é que ele não encontra o nome que esteja numa quebra de linha.

Comment: Tipo: Marques Leão Magalhães, assim acha com ou sem acentuação!

Comment: Mas: Marques Leão (Final de uma linha)
Magalhães (Inicio da próxima).

Comment: Substitua a quebra de linha por espaço. Editei minha resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia a todos!
Agradeço aos que se interessaram em me ajudar! Resolvi o problema fora da rotina, como precisava copiar o texto do diário oficial pro Memo, antes de "despeja-lo" lá, jogo no Notepad++, transformo em uma única linha e problema resolvido!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha resolvido. Mas para efeitos de ajudar as próximas pessoas que tiverem um problema semelhante, poderia dizer se a minha resposta funcionou ou não para seu caso? Eu havia proposto substituir a quebra de linha por um espaço, que teria o mesmo efeito que você executou fora da rotina.

Comment: Obrigado Cleber Griff! Não funcionou, inclusive, constatei que quando essa situação ocorre dentro do Word, com a busca do próprio, não funciona...

Comment: Nem com o ``.Replace(sLineBreak, ' ')`` ? Fiquei curioso rs